# If a class has bunch of member functions which modifies member variables. Can we say that none of them are thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex

I am learning about C++ threading. I have a class called `Shape` which has member variables called `mWidth` and `mHeight`. There's a member function called `Shape::setWH(int newWidth,int newHeight)` which modifies `mWidth` and `mHeight`. Multiple threads can perform this operation on same object right? so I can say its not thread safe and use std::mutex to lock the operation.

Comment: “ I can say its not thread safe and use std::mutex to lock the operation.” is debatable. Especially if your program has some kind of main thread that needs to keep running, using too many locks can be devastating for performance. But your assertion that function isn’t thread safe is correct.

Comment: `std::thread`, just to give an example, is thread-safe. It doesn't mean though that you can use modifying operations without synchronization though, so careful with the use of that term.

Comment: According to the standard multiple threads modifying an integer isn't thread safe but in reality on most processors it'll be an atomic operation. Whether the class as a whole is thread safe depends on the semantics of that class

Answer (score 1):

> If a class has bunch of member functions which modifies member variables. Can we say that none of them are thread safe?

Yes. If not stated otherwise you have to assume that methods are not thread-safe. Making each and every single method thread safe would be no good, because the caller needs to be in control of synchronization when they want more coarse grained synchronization (eg lock a mutex for many calls rather than every single call).

---

Types have to be assumed to be not thread-safe unless their methods are explicitly stated to be thread safe. Baking in synchronisation into each single method would be inefficient, because that would mean that the caller has no control over how to use them in a thread safe way.

Suppose the caller writes a tight loop, then they want to lock a mutex only once not in every iteration:

```
 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mymutex);
 for (int i=0;i <10000; ++i) {
    foo.setSomething(i);
 }
```

Or suppose a user is completely sure that no synchronization is needed, then locking a mutex anyhow is unecessary overhead.

It is completely ok to not provide the thread-safety you are worried about. As long as you do not claim that something would be thread-safe the caller should be aware that it isnt and that they need to use synchronization. What you should care about is that `const` should not just be logical constness but actual constness. For example:

```
 struct foo {
     int get42() const {
         ++calls;
         return 42;
     }
     private:
     mutable int calls = 0;
};
```

In a single-threaded context this is completely fine. From outside there is no way to see that calling `foo::get42` changed internal state. The method does not modify "logical state", it does however modify the binary state of the object. Avoid that and document when a non-const method is thread-safe. Then the caller should be ready to use your type in a thread-safe way.